# Visual Studio 2012 error (The input stream is not a valid binary format)

Tags: visual-studio-2012

My computer crashed when I was coding so I did a reset.

When I reopened my solution in VS 2012 I get the following error message:

After the computer crashed when I reopened the solution I select to recover the solution ...

Any ideas what's all about?

[image]

Comment: Careful playing poker on the Internet when you're at work, somebody may find out.  Running a disk check would be advisable.